# best method for finding all items with a combination hour and day

Tags: python, mysql, sql, indexing

I have a database with tens of thousands of items ( up to 100,000 ).  Each item can be checked at certain hours of the day and days of the week. eg.  item 1 can be checked at 1am, 5am, 7pm on Wed, Fri, Sun.  So there can be between 1 and 24 hours and 1 and 7 days on each item.

I am using MySQL as the database and coding in python.

What would be the fastest method of finding all items a combination of (h1, h2, h3) and (d1, d2) where h1-h3 are just specific hours in the day and d1-d2 are specific days in the week.

Is it as simple as creating an index based on hour+day OR is there are better way with arrays or pandas etc.

Comment: Python is not the issue here. It's a matter of how you construct your SQL query. The performance of that query will depend on how the database has been set up

Comment: In this (1am, 5am, 7pm on Wed, Fri, Sun), are there 9 possibilities:  Wed at 1am, Wed at 5am, etc?  Or are you looking for an item with all 3 dows and all 3 hours checked?  Or "find all rows with Fri and 7pm checked?

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting an a composite index on your table. One for day and one for time.  If the call is going to use both columns regularly this would improve the performance I would think.  It's worth a try if you are experiencing slow retrieval.  Just a side note:  If this table has a process set on it to write, update etc...  You would probably want to drop the index prior to those operations due to slowness on processing.  IE Stored Procedure, ETL (Informatica), etc...

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PYTHONAPPINDEX
ON MYSQLTABLE (DateColumn, TimeColumn)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am actually using Django as well so I created a manytomany field for hour and day of the week against the item.  I then created a class for Hours and Days.  In MySQL Django created two additional tables item_hours and item_days. When I save an hour to an item it creates a row in the item_hours table which is the id of the item and the id of the hours.  This is similar to your suggestion.  Thank you for taking the time to respond. It was helpful in building an understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?  An item can have only dow-hr combo:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE dow = 5 AND hr = 18

INDEX(dow, hr)  -- very fast
```

Or a column with 31 bits, any subset of 24 bits are set for hr and any subset of the other 7 bits for dow, then an item can have all combos of several dows and several hrs:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE dow_hr & ((1 << 5-1) | (1 << 18+6)
```

but it is slow due to a table scan because there may be other bits turned on.  (3+3) bits in your first example, 3+2) in the second.

It may (or may not) benefit from `INDEX(dow_hr)`